# Converting DateandTime to time and comparing with DB for validation

Tags: json, spring-boot, validation, datetime

I want to write a validation in such a way that my query should result true if same CCN and date already exist in DB, from JSON and IN DB datetime is saved in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", but in my validation i need to take only date[yyyy-MM-dd] and compare.

I am new to spring boot

This is what i have in my model class

```
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date datetime;
```

Repository for my class

```
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(c) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM TABLEX c WHERE c.ccn = :ccn and c.datetime= :datetime")
    boolean isExistbyCcnAndDate(@Param("ccn") String conveyancereferencenumber, @Param("datetime") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date date);
```

When i try this it gives result as always false.

This is how i am passing values to repository

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateString = sdf.format(model.getDatetime());
convertedDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
isExistCcnAndDate=repository.isExistbyCcnAndDate(model.getCcn(),convertedDate);
```

Comment: If your dateTime is saved in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and you try to compare it to yyyy-MM-dd this will always be false because you try to compare e.g. 2020-12-10 10:15:25 to 2020-12-10 00:00:00
You should try to find out how to format the c.datetime in your query(MySql: DATE_FORMAT) or maybe save date in other format redundant in you DB.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replay, i have added @Param("datetime") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date date); will that not work?

Comment: I  don't think so because @Param("datetime") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") will only format your input but not what is saved in the DB.

Comment: your query will look like
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(c) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM TABLEX c WHERE c.ccn = ABC123XXX and c.datetime= 2020-12-15
this will never match a date formatted by yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss pattern.

Comment: I want to format mvalue from myy input JSON and value from DB both into yyyy-MM-dd , both are inyyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss this format currently

Comment: As I said, you can find out how to cast c.datetime in sql, this depends on your sql server. I think MySQL provides date(c.datetime) MsSqlServer provides Date(c.datetime) since I don’t know which server you use I cannot help there. Or you could save a second property which is only date. Casting only the Input will not help.

Comment: I would try to solve this directly on the sql server before trying to fix the problem in Java code. 
You could first try what select c.datetime from TABLE c will give you as datetimes format, then try select date(c.datetime) from TABLE c, then trying to filter with where and so on. Btw you wrote „from TABLEX“ this may be a problem!

Comment: did that or my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my sqlfiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5305eb/3

Using sql fiddle this will work:
Create shema:

```
create table c(datetime DATETIME, ccn TEXT)
insert into c (datetime, ccn) values ('2020-01-01 10:10:50' , 'a');
```

Try to read and filter step by step:

```
select * from c;
select * from c where c.datetime = '2020-01-01 10:10:50';
select * from c where date(c.datetime)= date('2020-01-01');
```

As I already said, whether you can use date(), DATE() or whatever depends on your server, sqlfiddle is MySQL.